# How to keep compatible network adapters when moving from Win2008R2 to Win2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm migrating virtual machines from Win2008R2 hosts to a Win2012R2 host. Since [there is no direct import/export path due to the WMI namespace change](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2013/10/22/windows-hyper-v-2012-amp-8-1-hyper-v-did-not-find-virtual-machine-to-import.aspx) ("did not find virtual machines to import"), I recreate the VMs as new (Gen 1) and attach the old VHDs.

However, even though I set the network adapter MAC address to static using the MAC address the adapter had in the Win2008 config, after upgrading VM additions, the old device is "disconnected" and a new (and unconfigured) Hyper-V network adapter shows up.

I would really like to avoid that since the network setup of some of the VMs is complex. How can I get Hyper-V to present the network adapter in a way that the guest OS recognizes it as the old adapter and keeps all the settings?

Comment: Win2012 does support importing from Win2008R2 so doing the move in two steps might be easier overall if you have access to a system with Win2012.

Comment: I know, but I don't have a Win2012 (or Win8 without 8.1) installation at hand. However I overlooked that I can just copy the VMs from Win2008R2 and register them in-place at the new location, that works. At least for 2008R2. I also have a Win2008 (without R2) machine, and for these guests, I first have to export/import them to a Win2008R2 machine and from there copy them to Win2012R2. More cumbersome than expected, but works. However, I still did not find out what to do to _recreate_ a VM with a network adapter that is recognized by the guest as the old one...